# How to escape apostrophe or quotes on a JSP (used by JavaScript)

Tags: java, javascript, forms, jsp, escaping

I have a user form. If the user types in a string with `'` or `"` as part of it I have no problem. The form is submitted and saved correctly to the database. My problem is when I reload the page (all entries can be modified and are loaded into a list in the JSP before being displayed). On loading the page I get an error saying:

```
missing ) after argument list 'Caroline's message', \n
```

What do I need to do to escape this string for displaying it on the frontend?

Here is the code I am using on the frontend to read in the data and store it in a JavaScript object. I am not fully sure where I need to escape. The field causing the problem is c.getComName:

```
communications[<%=i%>][1] = new CommObject('<%=c.getComId()%>', '<%=c.getComName()%>');
```

**UPDATED WITH HTML GENERATED:**

```
communications[0][1] = new CommObject('101', 'Caroline's Message');
```

Comment: What do you mean by messed up? In what way are those characters messed up?

Comment: Sorry, further investigation revealed that my problem is not in submitting the form but on retrieving the data again after submission, see updated question

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML?

Comment: HTML added, I removed the second part of the question regarding jquery, after looking at the HTML this is the only place that has the ' in it so this is where I need it to be escaped.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the Apache [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript(java.lang.String)) function.

> ```
> Escapes the characters in a String using JavaScript String rules.
>
> Escapes any values it finds into their JavaScript String form.
> Deals correctly with quotes and control-chars (tab, backslash, cr, ff, etc.)
>
> So a tab becomes the characters '\\' and 't'.
> ```

Comment: Also, if this string is a URL (for example javascript:launchURL(<%=c.getComUrl()%>) you can combine this StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript with URLEncoder.encode to produce a javascript-safe URL.

Comment: Just note that this has been changed to `StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(String)` in commons lang 3.x+

Comment: It also converts any non-latin alphabetic symbol into its unicode sequence ("кириллица" -> "\\u043A\\u0438\\u0440\\u0438\\u043B\\u043B\\u0438\\u0446\\u0430"). The question was only about single quotes.

Comment: Another note, in newer versions of commons-lang3 this is marked as deprecated, in favor of the equivalent class from commons-text.

Answer (score 49):

I prefer to avoid scriptlets in the middle of my page and was having to use them (increasingly often) to escape strings when used in JavaScript code. I wanted an [Expression Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language#History) (EL) way of escaping the strings. I created a very small custom taglib that I use for just this purpose:

**Utilities.java:**

```
package com.mycom.taglibs;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class Utilities {
    public static String escapeJS(String value) {
        return StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(value);
    }
}
```

**mytaglib.tld:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

  <description>My Tag Library</description>
  <display-name>Tag Utils</display-name>
  <tlib-version>1.1</tlib-version>
  <short-name>myt</short-name>

  <function>
    <description>
        JavaScript Escape function
    </description>
    <name>escapeJS</name>
    <function-class>com.mycom.taglibs.Utilities</function-class>
    <function-signature>java.lang.String escapeJS(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
  </function>
</taglib>
```

**And, in the JSP page:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="myt" uri="/WEB-INF/mytaglib.tld" %>
The escaped string is: ${myt:escapeJS(variableHoldingTheString)}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good advice :) I would just add that you don't need the Utilities.java class. You can construct the taglib directly with StringEscapeUtils like so:

<function-class>org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils</function-class>
<function-signature>java.lang.String escapeJavaScript(java.lang.String)</function-signature>

Comment: Updating @machinery's answer with new package and function name: `<function-class>org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils</function-class> 
<function-signature>java.lang.String escapeEcmaScript(java.lang.String)</function-signature>`

However, I didn't use this answer because my taglib tag complained 
`The content of element type "taglib" must match "(tlibversion,jspversion?,shortname,uri?,info?,tag+)"` and I didn't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

`fn:escapeXml` does not work in JavaScript. It replaces `'` with `#&0039;` still causing an error when the JavaScript is executed.

Only escaping in the JavaScript manner is correct: `\'`

The Apache StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript function does this for you. Creating a taglib for it greatly simplifies matters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the JSTL escape function `fn:escapeXml()` to get rid of anomalies caused due to single quotes(`).
The following example demonstrates the difference.

For example:

```
<c:set var="string1" value="This is abc's first String."/>
<c:set var="string2" value="This is abc's second String."/>

<p>With escapeXml() Function:</p>
<p>string (1): ${fn:escapeXml(string1)}</p>

<p>Without escapeXml() Function:</p>
<p>string (2): ${fn:escapeXml(string2)}</p>
```

**RESULT**

> string (1): This is abc s first String.
>
> string (2): This is abc's second String.

Answer (score 2):

Also we have very nice solution from Spring:

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<spring:message code="${propertyName}" javaScriptEscape="true"/>
```

So, issue from the question of this post can be resolved in this way:

```js
communications[<%=i%>][1] = new CommObject('<spring:message code="${c.comId}" javaScriptEscape="true"/>', '<spring:message code="${c.comName}" javaScriptEscape="true"/> <%=c.getComName()%>');
```

Comment: I think this answer only works if `propertyName` points to a message in a MessageResource. For printing the actual text of propertyName, escaped, you want `text="${propertyName}"` instead. Very handy tag, though! I will use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When you return the HTML from the CommObject class add in the \" instead of the ' and before the name (e.g. Caroline's message)

Like this: return "\"" + comName + "\"";

Comment: Still no joy, I get missing ) after argument list '"Caroline's message"', \n.  Just to confirm I need to escape both ' and "

Comment: No, just escape the ", and leave out the single quote

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem while I was passing data from my servlet to my `JSP` then to my code Javascript to create `JSON` object so I need it `'` but it's rendered like `&#39 ;`  which can't be in the `JSON` object so to fixed I had simply to change my `JSP` from writing `'` to `` ` `` the 6 key and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

That's strange.

What about:

```
'<%=c.getComName().replaceAll("\\'","\\\\'")%>'
```

If that works, you just have to figure out how to add the \".

Comment: it actually doesn't fix it which is a surprise to me!

Comment: :-o I guess you'll need to preprocess the name before delivering it back to the front end. :(

Comment: Never ever write your own escaping code! You forgot for example to account for possible backslash characters in the original string. Use tried and tested code, like the mentioned `StringEscapeUtils`

Answer (score -2):

You could use JSP core tags:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>      
var jsVar = "<c:out value='${stringVariable}' />";
```

Comment: There is a difference between escaping text for Javascript and for HTML/XML. Your answer addresses the latter but this question was asking for the former. Because c:out will produce HTML/XML entities which don't always work in JS code.

Comment: You will be able to break the js context: "is extremely easy to switch into an execution context with characters including (but not limited to) semi-colon, equals, space, plus, and many more, so use with caution." from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Yup, injecting `</script><script>alert(1)</script><script>var jsVar2 = "foobar` should pop up the alert because browsers watch for `</script>` in the `<script>` context that includes the `var jsVar = ..` statement regardless of the string literal sub-context.  I think even injecting `"; alert(1); var jsVar2 = "foobar` will work. Thanks @Tarion