# problem with apostrophe in ajax webservice call

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, ajax, webservice-client

I'm calling a webservice using jQuery with .ajax

Here are the data parameters for the call:

```
  var parameters = "{'Titre':'" + Titre + "','Description':'" + Description + "','Contact':'" + Contact + "','VilleId':'" + VilleId + "','QuartierId':'" + QuartierId + "','UserId':'" + UserId + "'}";
```

It works fine. But when parameters `Description` or `Titre` contain the `'` character , no call!!!

Does anyone have an idea how can i make it work even with apostrophe character in `Titre` and/or `Description`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470768/how-to-escape-apostrophe-or-quotes-on-a-jsp-used-by-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a json encoder. Douglas Crockford's [JSON in JavaScript](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) seems a good choice.

Then you just write

```
 var param = JSON.stringify({ 'Titre': Titre, 'Description': Description });
```

and let the master worry about the quoting.

Comment: How can i precise that the question is answered.

Comment: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!) --  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping the apostrophe:

```
    var parameters = "{
         'Titre':'" + Titre.replace(/'/g,"\'") + 
//                          ^
        "','Description':'" + Description + 
        "','Contact':'" + Contact + 
        "','VilleId':'" + VilleId + 
        "','QuartierId':'" + QuartierId + 
        "','UserId':'" + UserId + "'}";
```

Comment: you mean Titre.replace(/'/g,"\\'")

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to encode the values to be safely passed in a URL.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/URLEncode

Answer (score 0):

You can try escaping it:

```
var str = "asdfsd'asdfadf";
str = str.replace("'", "\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I escape that works for me currently:

```
var theString = "O'Kief blahblahblahblah";
theString = theString .replace("'", "\\'");
//Note the double \\
```

Doesn't break and saves as: O'Kief blahblahblahblah