# Escape apostrophe in my jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, escaping, apostrophe

Hello i have this code in my jsp

```
<a href="#"onclick="supprimerProduit('<bean:write name="gererProduitsForm"  property="type_produit.nomProduit"/>','supprimerProduit','',<bean:write name="gererProduitsForm"  property="type_produit.idProduit"/>)"></a>
```

So i have an javascript error when i have for example

> Thoma's

in my var

```
<bean:write name="gererProduitsForm"  property="type_produit.nomProduit"/>
```

How can i do for escape the apostrophe..?
Thx

Comment: Hi, Mercer! Isn't your questin a duplcate of  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1470768?

Comment: perhaps but how can i use this http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29 in my jsp ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape apostrophe or quotes on a JSP ( used by javascript )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470768/how-to-escape-apostrophe-or-quotes-on-a-jsp-used-by-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

@brandizzi: This subject is different from the other one you linked to. Escaping an apostrophe on a db insert/update, or stripping an apostrophe on db select is a horse of a different color. Escaping an apostrophe in a url string, like the example in the original post here is a whole different kettle of wax.

To Mercer, this is my recommendation for escaping the apostrophe in a url string: Replace ' with %27

The **javascript** way to do it is like this:

my_title = "Who's to say we aren't all a dream?";

my_title = my_title.replace("'", "%27");

The **PHP** way to do it is:

$my_title = "Who's to say we aren't all a dream?";

$my_title = str_replace("'","%27",my_title);

Comment: Sorry, this answer is far from useful. In JavaScript it's too late already and the OP is not using PHP, but JSP with Struts.