# To escape character in javascript/jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have this code bit:

```
var description = '${requestScope.description}';
```

In the above code if

```
${requestScope.description} = '''''''''
```

IE is throwing script error. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You mean to same that description itself is a consecutive quotes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape apostrophe or quotes on a JSP ( used by javascript )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470768/how-to-escape-apostrophe-or-quotes-on-a-jsp-used-by-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you fix it using the technique mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1473192/476786 as suggested by [@xdazz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949364/to-escape-character-in-javascript-jsp#comment15920527_11949364).

If not, try using **double quotes** as follows:

```
var description = "${requestScope.description}";
```

---

Edit: OP says that `description` could also potentially contain **" (double quotes)**:

In that case, you could replace the double quotes before you output the string as:

```
var description = "${requestScope.description.replace("\"", "''")}";
```

This would replace all instances of double quotes with 2 single quotes.

---

Please note that my `jsp` isvery weak, and as such the code sample above might need a tweak or two... :)

Comment: @xdazz it is working for Apostrophe but if "${requestScope.description}" value is "(double quotes) it is not working again the same script error