# JQuery+Java setting field value with val() + single quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, quote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to escape apostrophe or quotes on a JSP ( used by javascript )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470768/how-to-escape-apostrophe-or-quotes-on-a-jsp-used-by-javascript)

I have a problem setting the value of a textarea element with jquery's val().

Basically, I have a JSP file which receives a string parameter called 'text'.

```
Java code:
String text = (String) request.getParameter("text");
```

Now I want my textarea element to receive this text:

```
Javascript code:
$('#textarea_id').val('<%=text%>');
```

It works when my text doesnt contain single quotes (and possibly other chars).

For example, for text =

```
test'
```

this error happens:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
$('#textarea_id').val('test'');
```

I hope you guys understand. I need a way to encode this value... i tried using escape so the quote is replaced by %27, but after unescaping its replaced again and the error happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because Javascript is using the ' character to determine where your string ends.  To include a literal quote in your string, escape the quote with a backslash.

```
$('#textarea_id').val('test\'');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single quote with the Java code. The final output should look like

```
.val('test\'')
```

Comment: So I have to escape my Java string before setting its value in the textarea? Think i got it... i'll try thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
$('#textarea_id').val('test \' ');
```