# Javascript function not working with variables having special character

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

Javascript function:

```
var Id ; //global variables
var Name; //global variables
function getServiceId(id,name){
    Id=id;
    Name = name;
    alert(Id);
}
```

And this my jsp code

```
<core:forEach var="service" items="${listServiceBO}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="Javascript:void(0);">
                                            ${service.name}
                                    </a></td>
                                    <td>${service.multiplicity}</td>
                                    <td>${service.scheduleType}</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" id="serviceDeleteButton(${service.id})" name="serviceDeleteButton" 
                                            onclick="getServiceId(${service.id},'${service.name}');" title="Delete"
                                            class="btn btn-link btn-inline" data-toggle="modal"
                                            data-target="#deleteServiceModal"> 
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Delete</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </core:forEach>
```

if my `service.name`  contains any special character....my values are not getting set in Javascript. But if I do not have any special character in that name then it is working fine.

Because of special character I am not able to set any of the two values. Any solution ???

Comment: can you put this on jsfiddle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470768/how-to-escape-apostrophe-or-quotes-on-a-jsp-used-by-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
onclick="getServiceId(${service.id},&quot;${service.name}&quot;);"
```

Or, the best thing to do would be escaping all values in Java:

```
Base64.encode(str);
```

and in Javascript doing a decode:

```
decodeURIComponent(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

## edit:

Try just escaping it:

```
var Id ; //global variables
var Name; //global variables
function getServiceId(id,name){
    Id=id;
    Name = escapeRegExp(name);
    alert(Id);
}

function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

jsp not strong suit,but maybe change this:

```
onclick="toggle('getServiceId(${service.id},'${service.name}')');"
```

to:

```
onclick="toggle('getServiceId(${service.id}, \"${service.name}\")')"
```