# JavaScript code is not getting called in marquee tag

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I am stuck in a weird problem. In my application data is getting passed from servlet to jsp and in jsp I am trying to split the data at `-`  and display in a marquee tag.

The problem I am facing is when I use the variable directly without splitting I am able to see the data on JSP page that is passed from servlet. Here is the code:

```
<label> starting <marquee id="marque" direction="up">${message}</marquee></label>
```

But when I am trying to split using JavaScript and use in marquee tag, nothing is getting displayed.

Code I am trying to split and use in marquee:

```
<label> starting <marquee id="marque" direction="up"></marquee></label>
<script> 

var count;
var getdata=${message};

storedata=getdata.split('-');
document.getElementById("marque").innerHTML = getdata.split('-').join('<br/>');

</script>
```

### Edit

This is the link

```
http://localhost:8080/Projectname/Landing.jsp
```

Edit2------------------------------------------------------

```
<label> starting<marquee id="marque" direction="up"></marquee></label>
<script> 

var count;
var getdata="nulldata1-
data2-
data3-
data4-
";

//Below part is comment in my code
//nulldata1-
data2-
data3-
data4-
";
// comment ends here

var storedata = new Array();
var displaydata;

storedata=getdata.split('-');
document.getElementById("marque").innerHTML = getdata.split('-').join('<br/>');


</script>
```

Comment: hint: why do you use single/double quotes around string literals in javascript?

Comment: @Lashane Honestly I couldn't find any difference we can use any one.. Did I miss anything? Can you please help where you are trying to guide me

Comment: imagine, variable message contains `word another word`, how final html code and script tag content will look like?

Comment: not sure why it is not working, it works when testing in browser

Comment: ok script tag content will be `getdata=word another word`... I guess I am getting your point, in the sense `word another word` won't be treated as string? am I getting it right?

Comment: @Siva exactly, this is invalid javascript, so of course browser stops its parsing because of syntax error

Comment: @loelsonk yes it works when I use the string in `${message}` instead of `${message}` in `getdata` variable

Comment: @Siva right, I've just tested it like so: `var count;
var getdata= 'message-text-demo';document.getElementById("marque").innerHTML = getdata.split('-').join('<br/>');`

Comment: @Lashane ok thanks for that in that case if I use `"${message}"` in `getdata` then also I am not getting anything, How can extract message and pass as string?

Comment: @Siva update your question with actual html you're getting in browser

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: @Lashane sir just added the link.. I am very much new to JSP and JS stuff please let me know if any more info need to be added. thanks

Comment: my network configuration does not allow me to open your localhost

Comment: No No sorry sir.. I am getting your point.. give me 2 sec will post what I am getting in browser

Comment: @Lashane edit2 is the exact part that i am getting in my browser

Comment: ok, so - javascript does not support multiline literals, also single line comments

Comment: yes sir you are correct... but this is what I am getting from servlet.. Do I need to change the way input is generated from servlet?

Comment: yes, servlet need to escape wrong symbols, new lines with `\n`, single/double quotes (if they could be in your data)

Comment: @Lashane sir you are awsome.... Thank you very much for guiding me as a tutor and showing me new dimension for debugging. I have changed the servlet code and now everything is working fine. Please post as answer will accept it.

Comment: Here is better answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470768/how-to-escape-apostrophe-or-quotes-on-a-jsp-used-by-javascript

Comment: @Lashane Thanks sir will go through it.. Also I have one more doubt.. what is best practice in the sense do we need to run the JSP or Servlet because both are opening the webpage but I want to know the best practice. Can you please comment a bit on this aswell. Actually I am new to this JSP and Servlet stuff I am more into SAP products and database part, Trying really hard to learn these concepts. thanks

Comment: People usually use jsp, I personally don't see difference

Answer (score -1):

getElementById is working with all type of html elements. I think you have an error in your code and your code don't run correctly. Please check your browser console error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but @Lashane sir helped me to solve the issue