# String with apostrophe from Java to Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, string, jsp

On java (controller) I have a string that can contain an apostrophe. I send this string to the jsp page and the string is extracted in this way:

```
 var intestatarioLibString = '${libretto.intestatarioLib};
```

(I send the object libretto which contains the string).

The problem is the apostrophe, if the string contains an apostrophe, the string is "cut" where the apostrophe is. Sample:

If the string that I send is 'DEL PIERO' ALESSANDRO' ,
when I open the jsp on browser I met an error because the debugger read like:

```
 var intestatarioLibString = 'DEL PIETRO' ALESSANDRO
```

So, the apostrophe is considered the end of the string. The problem is that I can't replace the apostrophe, I need it. Can someone can give me a hand please?

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470768/how-to-escape-apostrophe-or-quotes-on-a-jsp-used-by-javascript

Comment: "On Java"? Java doesn't have a `var` keyword. None of the code samples seem valid. Are you generating JavaScript in a JSP page? To escape apostrophes, use something like URL encoding.

Comment: you should escape the apostrophe like this way 'del piero\' alessandro' or use double quotes

Comment: The code was from javascript, coglione.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the characters in javascript string, for this you can use [org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the string just try :

```
var intestatarioLibString = escape("DEL PIETRO' ALESSANDRO");
```